# Scanning multiple line data from .txt file into struct array

Tags: c

I have a text file where info looks like this:

```
he he 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
ne ne 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

and I can keep adding to it.
What I want to do is have a function that reads that info and puts in into struct array, but I'm having trouble with pointers and figuring out how to read one line, then next one etc. I'm aware function that reads atm is broken, I tried bunch of stuff and could not figure it out. Sorry if its a bit silly question.

Source.c

```
int main(void) {
int opcija=0;
U *ucenici=NULL;



while(opcija !=4){
    printf("Odaberite opciju:\n 1.Stvaranje datoteke ucenici.txt\n 2.Upisivanje novog ucenika\n 3.Pregled ucenika\n 4.Izlaz iz programa\n");
    scanf("%d", &opcija);
switch (opcija) {
case 1:
    kreiranje();
    break;

case 2:
    dodavanje();
    break;
case 3:
    void citanje1(U *ucenici);
    int j=brojanjelinija();
    for (int i = 0;i < j; i++) {
        printf("%d. %s %s\n", i + 1, ucenici[i].ime, ucenici[i].prezime);
    }
}


}
return 0;
}




void citanje1(U **ucen) {
    FILE* pok = NULL;
    pok = fopen("ucenici.txt", "r");
    int broj = brojanjelinija();
    ucen = (U**)malloc(broj * sizeof(U*));
    for (int i = 0;i < broj;i++) {
        fscanf(pok, "%s %s %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d \n", ucen[i]->ime, ucen[i]->prezime, ucen[i]->dan, ucen[i]->mjesec, ucen[i]->godina, ucen[i]->mat, ucen[i]->hrv, ucen[i]->eng, ucen[i]->hidr, ucen[i]->fiz, ucen[i]->term, ucen[i]->oet, ucen[i]->tehmat);
    }

    free(ucen);
}
```

Header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H



typedef struct ucenik{
    char ime[10];
    char prezime[10];
    int* dan;
    int* mjesec;
    int* godina;
    int* mat;
    int* hrv;
    int* eng;
    int* hidr;
    int* fiz;
    int* term;
    int* oet;
    int* tehmat;

}U;
void kreiranje(void);
void dodavanje();
int brojanjelinija();
void citanje1(U);
#endif // HEADER_H
```

Answer (score 2):

All your `ucinek` data members that you want to use to store integers should actually store `int` instead of `int*`:

```
int dan;
int mjesec;
...etc...
```

Remember that a pointer tells the compiler where to find some other data, rather than storing a meaningful value itself.

Your [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) line should then change to pass pointers to the integers, which you can get using the `&` operator:

```
fscanf(pok, "%s %s %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",
       ucen[i]->ime, ucen[i]->prezime, &ucen[i]->dan, &ucen[i]->mjesec,
       &ucen[i]->godina, &ucen[i]->mat, &ucen[i]->hrv, &ucen[i]->eng,
       &ucen[i]->hidr, &ucen[i]->fiz, &ucen[i]->term, &ucen[i]->oet,
       &ucen[i]->tehmat);
```

Those pointers tell [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) where to store the parsed values.

I never use [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) without checking the returned value either: it says how many values were successfully parsed from the input and stored.  If it's not the number you're expecting, you should print an error message.

Comment: Lot of pointer stuff I did was just testing out to try and fix it, thanks for explaining it! I still have an issue of how to read other lines, I know my if is wrong, I can't think of any other way.